# Stream a file to the HTTP response in Pylons

Tags: python, http, pylons

I have a Pylons controller action that needs to return a file to the client. (The file is outside the web root, so I can't just link directly to it.) The simplest way is, of course, this:

```
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        response.write(f.read())
```

That works, but it's obviously inefficient for large files. What's the best way to do this? I haven't been able to find any convenient methods in Pylons to stream the contents of the file. Do I really have to write the code to read a chunk at a time myself from scratch?

Comment: For serving files, make sure you open them in `rb` mode, so you don't get mangled results running on a Windows server.

Comment: Good point, bobince - changed it to 'rb'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work using the `FileApp` class, thanks to **Chris AtLee** and **THC4k** (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836191/how-can-i-set-a-custom-response-header-for-pylons-static-public-files/837561#837561)). This method also allowed me to set the Content-Length header, [something Pylons has a lot of trouble with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777866/content-length-header-not-returned-from-pylons-response), which enables the browser to show an estimate of the time remaining.

Here's the complete code:

```
def _send_file_response(self, filepath):
    user_filename = '_'.join(filepath.split('/')[-2:])
    file_size = os.path.getsize(filepath)

    headers = [('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=\"' + user_filename + '\"'),
               ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
               ('Content-Length', str(file_size))]

    from paste.fileapp import FileApp
    fapp = FileApp(filepath, headers=headers)

    return fapp(request.environ, self.start_response)
```

Answer (score 8):

The correct tool to use is shutil.copyfileobj, which copies from one to the other a chunk at a time.

Example usage:

```
import shutil
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f, response)
```

This will not result in very large memory usage, and does not require implementing the code yourself.

The usual care with exceptions should be taken - if you handle signals (such as SIGCHLD) you have to handle EINTR because the writes to response could be interrupted, and IOError/OSError can occur for various reasons when doing I/O.

Comment: Well, it SEEMED to work, but I tried it with a 2GB file recently and found that it still took a very long time to return anything and the memory usage of the process went to 2.5GB. So it appears that the Pylons response still buffers the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that WSGI, and pylons by extension, work with iterable responses.  So you should be able to write some code like (warning, untested code below!):

```
def file_streamer():
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            block = f.read(4096)
            if not block:
                break
            yield block
response.app_iter = file_streamer()
```

Also, `paste.fileapp.FileApp` is designed to be able to return file data for you, so you can also try:

```
return FileApp(filepath)
```

in your controller method.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help. The `file_streamer` method returns the data, but it all still gets buffered. When I try to return `FileApp(filepath)` I get "TypeError: 'FileApp' object is not iterable"

Comment: Ah, looks like it just needs a little bit more code than that, but essentially `FileApp` does what I want. I'll post the complete answer separately. Thank you! +1

Comment: return forward(FileApp(filepath))