# Content-Length header not returned from Pylons response

Tags: python, http, pylons, content-length

I'm still struggling to [Stream a file to the HTTP response in Pylons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413707/stream-a-file-to-the-http-response-in-pylons). In addition to the original problem, I'm finding that I cannot return the Content-Length header, so that for large files the client cannot estimate how long the download will take. I've tried

```
response.content_length = 12345
```

and I've tried

```
response.headers['Content-Length'] = 12345
```

In both cases the HTTP response (viewed in Fiddler) simply does not contain the Content-Length header. How do I get Pylons to return this header?

(Oh, and if you have any ideas on making it stream the file please reply to the original question - I'm all out of ideas there.)

**Edit:** while not a generic solution, for serving static files [`FileApp` allows sending the Content-Length header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413707/stream-a-file-to-the-http-response-in-pylons/2779020#2779020). For dynamic content it looks like **Alex Martelli**'s answer is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of middleware code [here](https://projects.openplans.org/melkjug/browser/melkjug/trunk/melkjug/lib/contentlength.py) that ensures all responses get a content length header if they're missing it.  You could tweak it so that you set some other header in your response (say 'X-The-Content-Length') and the middleware uses that to make the content length if the latter's missing.  I view the whole thing as a workaround for what I consider a pylons bug (its cavalier attitude to content length!) but apparently the pylons authors disagree with me on that score, so it's nice to at least have workarounds for it!-)

Comment: Thanks, Alex, that bit of middleware works. I don't even need to modify it - since I can't get the "streaming" to work anyway calling `len(body)` returns the correct value. I'm not sure why such a simple thing requires a bit of "middleware", though.

Congratulations on hitting 100K, by the way!

Comment: @evgeny, if you can convince the Pylons committers that content length _should_ always be returned, you'll earn everybody's gratitude including mine -- but it seems they're still convinced otherwise.  Thanks for the congrats!-)

Comment: Well, never mind "always", but at least if I manually set it in the headers it should be returned!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
response.headerlist.append((str("Content-Length"), str(" 123456")))
```