# how to serve downloadable PDF using pylons and paste server

Tags: pdf, pylons, paster

I have a directory of .pdf files and I want a user to click on name of a file and have it downloaded.

How can I do that with paste server in pylons?

Comment: Can you specify which part of this task you have problem with? If you are just starting out with Pylons and want to know how to do anything at all, consider reading up beginner tutorials or Pylons Book http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/introducing-pylons.html

Comment: I got it to work. My mistake was that I used POST method in my form, rather than GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this thread contains the answer to my question:

[How can I set a custom response header for pylons static (public) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836191/how-can-i-set-a-custom-response-header-for-pylons-static-public-files)